# Puffing Billy with Poltergeist error: "rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

Using the [Puffing Billy instructions for rspec with capybara](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy#setup-for-capybara) I created a simple test to stub a request using the `:poltergeist_billy` driver resulting in error:

```
ArgumentError:
        rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb:16:in `initialize'
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara.rb:372:in `new'
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara.rb:372:in `block in <top (required)>'
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:79:in `driver'
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:227:in `visit'
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
      # ./spec/scraypa_spec.rb:52:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

With this code:

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require "bundler/setup"
require "scraypa"
require 'billy/capybara/rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Enable flags like --only-failures and --next-failure
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = ".rspec_status"

  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :expect
  end

  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

spec/my_spec.rb:

```
it "should utilise capybara to download web content" do
  #Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist_billy
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist_billy
  proxy.stub('http://www.google.com/')
        .and_return(:text => "test response")
  visit "http://www.google.com/"
  expect(page.text).to eq('test response')
end
```

While digging around, I found an example that used `Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist_billy` (which I have commented out in my test above), if I uncomment that code, I then get this error:

```
Cliver::Dependency::NotFound:
        Could not find an executable ["phantomjs"] on your path.
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/cliver-0.3.2/lib/cliver/dependency.rb:143:in `raise_not_found!'
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/cliver-0.3.2/lib/cliver/dependency.rb:116:in `detect!'
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/cliver-0.3.2/lib/cliver.rb:24:in `detect!'
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.9.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client.rb:36:in `initialize'
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.9.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client.rb:14:in `new'
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.9.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client.rb:14:in `start'
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.9.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:42:in `client'
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.9.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:25:in `browser'
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.9.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:95:in `visit'
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:227:in `visit'
      # /home/resrev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
      # ./spec/scraypa_spec.rb:52:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Im not sure where to go from here or what im doing wrong, any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are many here, so let's just start at the beginning

1. You don't have `require capybara/rails` in your spec_helper.rb or rails_helper.rb - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#setup - this means Capybara.app isn't getting set and is why you're getting the "rack-test requires a rack application" - of course you don't really want to be using the `rack-test` driver for your current test which #3 will deal with.
2. Capybara already includes Capybara::DSL into feature specs, so use feature specs, and remove the `include Capybara::DSL` from your RSpec config shown above. This requires either putting your spec file into `spec/features/my_spec.rb` and enabling the RSpec config to determine test type by directory, or manually specifying that the test is a feature spec

   ```
   feature "should utilise capybara to download web content" do
     ...
   end
   ```

   or

   ```
   it "should utilise capybara to download web content", type: :feature do
     ...
   end
   ```
3. Your test is actually using the `rack_test` driver and not the `poltergeist-billy` driver.  This is because you're setting `Capybara.javascript_driver` inside the test.  It needs to be set before the test, and then the test tagged with metadata to tell it to use the specific driver.  Two options here, either set `Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist_billy` in your spec_helper.rb and then specify `:js` metadata

   ```
    feature "should utilise capybara to download web content", :js do
      ...
    end
   ```

   or specify `:driver` metadata to identify which driver to use for the given test

   ```
   feature "should utilise capybara to download web content", driver: :poltergeist_billy do 
     ... 
   end
   ```
4. When specifying to use poltergeist with billy you need to install PhantomJS (required by Poltergeist) in your path.  If using OSX with homebrew you can do `brew install phantomjs` - on other systems you'll need to download the latest version of PhantomJS and put it somewhere in your PATH
5. `expect(page.text).to eq('test response')`. This is a terrible way to do text matching when using Capybara.  `eq` has no waiting/retrying behavior and since actions have no guarantees on being completed when Capybaras methods return will lead to flaky tests.  Instead, use the matchers Capybara provides.  If you are okay with a substring match do

   `expect(page).to have_text('test_response')`

   if it needs to be an exact match

   `expect(page).to have_text('test_response', exact: true)`